# changing the project name on every build

Tags: cmake

I have a custom makefile used for versioning.
It basically sets the version according to some predefined rules and fetching info from git repo
I want to intergrate it with the esp32 cmake project.
Till now i managed to run the makefile from the cmakelist.txt file using

add_custom_target(versioning ALL
COMMAND  ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -P "sometext.cmake"
)

and in the sometext.cmake i am calling the makefile which sets a FirmwareVersion variable.

I use this variable in the root cmakelist.txt to set the project(${FirmwareVersion})

But i want the project name to be changed every time firmwareVersion is changed.

But project command is only if there is some changes in cmakelist.txt

Any help to accomplish it is highly apreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Reconfiguring the project for every single build seems like a bad idea to me. Also changing the project name does little to change the build results. Could you explain the desired outcome of the change and what the version number is actually based on? (Is it just a number counting up? If so how do you synchronize this across different machines?)

Comment: It is the tag taken from the git versioning and appending them to the name of the binaries to get the status of the git repo from the binary name

Answer (score 2):

The [`project()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/project.html) command also has `VERSION` named keyword. That is what you actually want. You can store the actual version in some extra CMake file (like `version.cmake`)

```
set(VERSION_FROM_GIT "1.2.3+9a6b075")
```

and use like

```
include("${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/version.cmake")
project(MyProject VERSION ${VERSION_FROM_GIT} ...)
...
```

It's up to you how you going to update this file... There are plenty of ways to do that.

Comment: But this project call is only done in the cmake file which only runs if cmake file or the directories are changed  time so if my git version changes it did not append the new git version to the binaries

Comment: @ankish It totally depends on how you gonna update the `version.cmake`. E.g., you may run `git describe` or `git rev-parse` from CMake or as a custom output/target... Some target of your project may have a dependency on it or a pre/post-build step... Those options first came to my mind... I don't know your goals and why you wanted to change a project **name** instead of version %)

Answer (score 0):

You can tell cmake to do a reconfiguration if a file changes. Since the `.git` directory contains a `HEAD` file either denoting the commit hash of the detached head or a reference to the file containing the commit hash, you could these files as configuration dependencies.

```
# assume the .git directory is in the same directory as this CMakeLists.txt
set(GIT_HEAD_FILE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/.git/HEAD")

# add dependency to the head itself
set_property(DIRECTORY . APPEND PROPERTY CMAKE_CONFIGURE_DEPENDS "${GIT_HEAD_FILE}")

file(READ "${GIT_HEAD_FILE}" GIT_HEAD_CONTENT)

if (GIT_HEAD_CONTENT MATCHES "ref: +([^ ]+)")
    # add file referenced in HEAD for non detached head state
    set_property(DIRECTORY . APPEND PROPERTY CMAKE_CONFIGURE_DEPENDS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/.git/${CMAKE_MATCH_1}")
endif()

... your logic depending on the git version goes here ...
```

This gets a bit more complicated if you intend on using your repository as submodule of another repo, since the `.git` directory is not necessarily located in the submodule.

Comment: Tried to use these dependency commands # assume the .git directory is in the same directory as this CMakeLists.txt
set(GIT_HEAD_FILE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/.git/HEAD")

# add dependency to the head itself
set_property(DIRECTORY . APPEND PROPERTY CMAKE_CONFIGURE_DEPENDS "${GIT_HEAD_FILE}")                                                                                                                 but somehow no reconfiguration happening even if i change the git tags

Comment: I did not claim that there could not be false positives. Another scenario would be checking out a different branch that points to the current commit: This changes the content of the `HEAD` file to reference a different file but that file may contain the same commit hash. There's no way for cmake to tell this without checking the file contents though. The only way to avoid this I see is integrating a git hook skript that updates some file only if the commit actually changed, but you'll need additional setup after each cloning of repo for this to work...

Comment: Note that this could be improved on if you did not require a change to happen that leads to a reconfiguration of the whole project. E.g. if you were satisfied with the contents of a header changing based on the commit hash, you could simply use a custom command to generate that header which does not require a reconfiguration of the whole project.

Comment: cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
include(C:/Projekt/Lapp/src/predictive-maintenance-box.pmb-software/Versioning.cmake)
add_custom_target(versioning ALL
DEPENDS version_tag
)

add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT version_tag
    POST_BUILD
    COMMAND  ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -P "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Versioning.cmake" 
    )
set_property(
    DIRECTORY
    APPEND 
    PROPERTY CMAKE_CONFIGURE_DEPENDS 
    "firmwareversion"
    )
include($ENV{IDF_PATH}/tools/cmake/project.cmake)

project(lapppdm_${FirmwareVersion}_FW)    this is the CMakeLists file i am using

Comment: execute_process(
   COMMAND cs-make -f "../mk/detect_git_generate_version.mk"
   RESULT_VARIABLE CMD_ERROR
   OUTPUT_VARIABLE CMD_OUTPUT
   OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE)
MESSAGE( STATUS "CMD_ERROR:" ${CMD_ERROR})
MESSAGE( STATUS "CMD_OUTPUT:" ${CMD_OUTPUT})
string(REGEX MATCH "FileName: [^ $]+" FileName ${CMD_OUTPUT})
string(REGEX MATCH "V[^ $]+" FirmwareVersion ${FileName})
file(WRITE firmwareversion ${FirmwareVersion})
this is the cmake script i am using to change the content of file firmwareversion but file not changing wo reconfig CMakeLists